# Divide by from selected columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, division, multiple-columns

Sorry if the question was asked before i try search but not found. I'm still new on mssql so
maybe the answer are obvious just i cant find.

My current query is:

```
SELECT gold_min, gold_max, gold_min_2, gold_max_2
FROM m_rdb
```

I want to divide the values on current columns by 20 and then update, just not sure how to do.
Any help are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
update m_rdb
set col=col/20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your updating the values to same columns then**

```
Update m_rdb SET gold_min = gold_min/20, gold_max=gold_max/20,
gold_min_2=gold_min_2/20, gold_max_2=gold_max_2/20
```

If your updating the values to Other columns then

```
Update m_rdb SET gold_min_other = gold_min/20, gold_max_other=gold_max/20,
gold_min_2_other=gold_min_2/20, gold_max_2_other=gold_max_2/20
```